# Python Webscraping List Items

Tags: python, web-scraping

We have an internal web page with lists of IP addresses.  The IP addresses are enclosed as list items.  I am still somewhat new to Python and was hoping for a bit of direction.  I would like to end up with a text file that comma separates these IPs.

```
<li>192.168.1.1</li>
```

I am using a publicly available website for my question, but the HTML source is similar.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_lists_intro'
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
list_items = soup.find_all('li')
print(list_items)

[<li>Coffee</li>, <li>Tea</li>, <li>Milk</li>, <li>Coffee</li>, <li>Tea</li>, <li>Milk</li>]
```

How can I further parse the output from list_items into a list/text file such as the following:

Coffee, Tea, Milk, Coffee, Tea, Milk

Thank You!

Comment: `print([e.text for e in list_items])`

Comment: Or if you just want a string: `print(", ".join([e.text for e in list_items]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply adding the entire tags to your list, instead of their text content.

```
list_items = ", ".join([li.text for li in soup.find_all("li")])
print(list_items)
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for their suggestions! This helps a new python person like myself a lot!